# Can I omit "any" in the sentences?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, determiners

Is "any" really necessary in the following sentences? If I omit in the sentences will that be grammatical?

Here are some examples:

1- When I reached John's home, I heard the barking of dogs. I asked john if there are **(any)** dogs in his house because I am scared of dogs.

2- Are there **(any)** ghosts in the world? What's your opinion, John? I don't believe there are **(any)** ghosts in the world.

3- Are there **(any)** humans who are immortal and can do anything they want.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you *can* omit **any** in examples 1, 2 & 3, and the sentences are still correct, although personally I would keep **any** in the sentences.

I suppose **any** makes the sentence a little more specific, like:

> Are there any ghosts (even one ghost) in the world?

or the difference between:

> I want a girl to marry me some day.

versus

> I want *any* girl to marry me *any* day.

**Any** makes me appear more desperate in this case.  :)

I know you didn't ask this but in:

> Can any native speaker please answer this question?

...**any** is *not* optional.  :)